# No logarithmic line showing up in the code

Tags: r

```r
ggplot (Zombie, aes(x=Mean_Temp, y=Percent_Infected)) +
   stat_smooth(method="lm", aes (color="Linear")) + 
   stat_smooth(method="loess", aes(color="Loess")) +  
   stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ a * log(x) +b,
       aes(color = "logarithmic"),se=F,start = list(a=1,b=1)) + 
   geom_point()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run the code the logarithmic line won't show up. And the error says:No starting values specified for some parameters. Initializing ‘a’, ‘b’ to '1.'. Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model

Comment: Consider that nobody knows what `Zombie` is but you. Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

**Shortcut**: you probably don't need `nls()`, since `y~a*log(x)+b` is actually a linear model.  Try `method="lm", formula=y~log(x)` ...

Guessing here since you haven't shown us a data set, but try `method.args= list(start = list(a=1,b=1))`. `ggplot` only knows about a small subset of the possible arguments to a fitting function like `nls` or `lm`, everything that's model-specific (like `start`) needs to be passed through `model.args()`

Also, try the `nls()` fit *outside* of `ggplot` first to make sure that your starting values work OK/you get sensible results.